# Trying to display events of a calendar in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, calendar

I am creating a calendar with events.
I used another library to create the calendar, but when I go to display the events, I can't get them to print in a list.
I tried using a TextView but it didn't work, so I tried with a ListView.

The ArrayAdapter can't call `events` as `events` is created in the for loop, yet when I put in the for loop it won't work.

> cannot resolve constructor

I was wondering if is there something I am doing wrong?
Can I display it in a TextView instead?

```
Event ev1 = new Event(Color.GREEN, 1488052800000L, footballEv);

public void onDayClick(Date dateClicked) {

    List<Event> events = compactCalendarView.getEvents(dateClicked);

    ArrayAdapter<Event> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Event>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, event);


    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> cannot resolve constructor

You can check the API documentation for what constructors are available.

Look here...

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this,  // Context
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,  // resource 
        event  // Error! Not a List<String>
);
```

If you want to show a list of Events, you need an `ArrayAdapter<Event>`.

And you should not need a loop to display them.

```
private ListView listView;
private ArrayAdapter<Event> adapter;
private List<Event> events;

public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    ...

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    events = new ArrayList<Event>();

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Event>(
        this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
        events);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);     
}

private void onDateClicked(Date clicked) {
    adapter.clear();
    adapter.addAll(compactCalendarView.getEvents(dateClicked));
}
```

Note: The `Event` class needs a `toString()` method.

Ref: [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4#29140403)

Comment: You are correct, I took it out of a loop and changed the `<String>` to `<Event>` but I still have the same error.

it is in a 
`public void onDayClick(Date dateClicked){
} `
method I don't know if that is why it isn't working?

Comment: Your question edit shows the use of an `event` variable that doesn't exist at all...

Comment: The `event` was in the for loop `for (Event event:events)` as you said I did not need to use a for loop I got rid of it. If I instead use `events` it still doesn't work the previous way it worked was with `event` and a for loop printing into a TextView but it wouldn't go onto separate lines so I changed it to a ListView.
PS: I keep hitting enter for a new line and it sends the comment so I edit it, then you have already responded to it >:

Comment: Yes, it was, but your edit makes the question not compile also... I don't really know what error you get, but I updated my answer with how I would write the code

Comment: What does `adapter.addAll()` need? The code you wrote is so close to working but I need to put `event` in their for some reason, converting it to a String or Object just gives an error _cannot resolve method_

Comment: `addAll()` takes a `Collection<T>` where `T` is defined as the Object type that is defined from `ArrayAdapter<T>`. In other words, `List<Event>` is an option, but not one `Event`